# Openshift SCC's and InitContainers

Tags: openshift, okd

I'd like to know if the `initContainers` in `kubernetes` are subject to the same restrictions that the app containers are? specifically I want to do a `chown` by the root before running a non-root container
Would this work for Anyuid or Restricted SCC profiles?

Comment: All containers in the pod are restricted to the same profile.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton thank you. Makes very much sense